# CUDA memory allocation issues with large images

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a function for making a histogram from an image (sequential version given (Homework))

```
CImg< unsigned char > histogramImage = CImg< unsigned char >(BAR_WIDTH * HISTOGRAM_SIZE, HISTOGRAM_SIZE, 1, 1);
unsigned int *histogram;
histogram = (unsigned int *)malloc(HISTOGRAM_SIZE * sizeof(unsigned int));
 memset(reinterpret_cast< void * >(histogram), 0, HISTOGRAM_SIZE * sizeof(unsigned int));

cudaMemset(gpuImage, 0, grayImage.width() * grayImage.height() * sizeof(unsigned char));

cuda_err = cudaMemcpy(gpuImage, grayImage, grayImage.width() * grayImage.height() * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
if (cuda_err != cudaSuccess)
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: Failed cudaMemcpy" << std::endl;
   return -1;
}

unsigned int *gpuhistogram;
cuda_err = cudaMalloc((void **)(&gpuhistogram), HISTOGRAM_SIZE * sizeof(unsigned int));
if (cuda_err != cudaSuccess)
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: Failed cudaMalloc" << std::endl;
}
cudaMemset (gpuhistogram, 0, HISTOGRAM_SIZE * sizeof(unsigned int));

histogram1D(gpuImage, histogramImage, grayImage.width(), grayImage.height(), gpuhistogram, HISTOGRAM_SIZE, BAR_WIDTH, total, gridSize, blockSize);

cuda_err = cudaMemcpy(histogram, gpuhistogram, HISTOGRAM_SIZE * sizeof(unsigned int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
if (cuda_err != cudaSuccess)
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: Failed cudaMemcpy" << std::endl;
}
```

That calls

```
void histogram1D(unsigned char *grayImage, unsigned char *histogramImage, const int width, const int height, unsigned int *histogram, const unsigned int HISTOGRAM_SIZE, const unsigned int BAR_WIDTH, NSTimer &timer, dim3 grid_size, dim3 block_size) {

NSTimer kernelTime = NSTimer("kernelTime", false, false);

kernelTime.start();
histo <<< grid_size, block_size >>> (grayImage, histogram,width);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
kernelTime.stop();

cout << fixed << setprecision(6);
cout << "histogram1D (kernel): \t\t" << kernelTime.getElapsed() << " seconds." << endl;
}
```

The kernel function is

```
__global__ void histo(unsigned char *inputImage, unsigned int *histogram, int width)
{

int x = threadIdx.x + (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x);
int y = threadIdx.y + (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y);

unsigned int index = static_cast< unsigned int >(inputImage[(y * width) + x]);
atomicAdd(&histogram[index],1);
}
```

The problem I have is, when I call this with images ranging from 1024x1024 to 3543x2480, it works. However, I have one image which is 8192x8192 and when the function returns, the values in *histogram are all still 0. My trials seems to indicate it has to do with the memory allocation for *gpuhistogram (shouldn't unsigned int be large enough?)since the sequential version of this works. How do fix this? Any ideas?

Comment: wrap every command in cudaSafeCall

Comment: check the return value of cudaDeviceSynchronize()

Comment: cudaDeviceSynchronize() returns cudaSuccess. 
Implementing cudaSafeCall now

Comment: @Mikhail, implemented safe call. No errors from any line. also doing cudaGetLastError() after kernel call. Still no errors

Comment: @Mikhail Just in case, by "no errors", i mean the problem persists without reporting any errors from the calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check your card. From wikipedia:

   Technical specifications    Compute capability (version)
   1.0    1.1     1.2     1.3     2.x     3.0     3.5
   Maximum dimensionality of grid of thread blocks    2   3
   Maximum x-, y-, or z-dimension of a grid of thread blocks  65535   231-1
2. I suspect your histogram will perform worse than a CPU code, try to use something like shared memory and assume 256 values. The trick is to use bin# of threads per block (256 threads per block). I don't want to destroy an author's income so see `CUDA by Example 2010`

Comment: GTX480, version - 2.x, Maximum DIM - 3, Maximum xyz - 65535

Comment: @masoftheund anyways I think your code is bad and I would fix it before moving on.

Comment: OK. trying to do that now. Don't really have much time for "perfect" code though

Comment: nice book! implemented the using shared memory. Can't say it performs any better than what I already had and I still get wrong results for the large image (which with the shared memory implementation takes over 16 seconds!!)

Comment: The problem was with dimensions of the grid and block.
I was using (width*height/threads) for my grid and for that file it was exactly 65536, cos i can only use 1024 threads per block.

Now using 
`dim3 blockSize(16, 16, 1);`
`dim3 gridSize((inputImage.width() + blockSize.x -1)/blockSize.x,(inputImage.height() + blockSize.y - 1) / blockSize.y, 1);`

**NOTE: Still don't fully understand it though**

Comment: @masoftheund Independent, I would strongly encourage you to time the CPU and GPU implementation.

Comment: I do. The GPU times are now adequate. Current problem I'm facing is converting a sequential image smoothing algorithm to work on the images. Could you help me out with that?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add; this is what I'm doing now, following Mikhail's answer;

```
void histogram1D(unsigned char *grayImage, unsigned char *histogramImage, const int width, const int height, unsigned int *histogram, const unsigned int HISTOGRAM_SIZE, const unsigned int BAR_WIDTH, NSTimer &timer, dim3 grid_size, dim3 block_size) {

NSTimer kernelTime = NSTimer("kernelTime", false, false);


kernelTime.start();
// Kernel
histo <<< 15*2, 256 >>> (grayImage, histogram,width,height);//15 is the number of blocks for my device
//cudaDeviceSynchronize(); //i get slow results with this. figured it's not nessesary since the kernel threads are synced.
kernelTime.stop();

cout << fixed << setprecision(6);
cout << "histogram1D (kernel): \t\t" << kernelTime.getElapsed()*1000 << " milliseconds." << endl;
}
```

Kernel Code;

```
__global__ void histo(unsigned char *inputImage, unsigned int *histogram, int width, int height)
{
__shared__ unsigned int temp[256];
temp[threadIdx.x] = 0;

__syncthreads();

int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int offset = blockDim.y * gridDim.x;
while(i<width*height)
{
    atomicAdd(&temp[inputImage[i]],1);
    i += offset;
}

__syncthreads();
atomicAdd(&(histogram[threadIdx.x]),temp[threadIdx.x]);
}
```